# Get Total of Grid and Show on Label in DataList both Grid and Label are Inside DataList

Tags: asp.net, grid, datalist

I have a DataList. Label and Grid are Inside ItemTemplate of DataList i have Bound the Grid noe i want to show Total Of Grid Column in Label . Which is Placed in Parent control of Grid

Comment: Can you provide your code and please be specific what exactly u want.

Comment: Please be clear. Do you want to show the total no. of columns or the total of a column? Also post your code. It will give a picture of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can Count the giridview columns by using this code:

```
int colCount = GridView1.Items[0].Cells.Count;
```